# Docker container: exit code 1 but no error message

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Angular project (currently just the result of `ng new ...`) inside a docker container. The container is running the command `ng build --watch` to rebuild on source code changes. A separate docker container runs Nginx to allow me to view the result. The basic mechanics of all this appear to be working fine: I can edit source code, hit refresh in the browser and see the changes.

When I stop the containers, the nginx container exits cleanly, but the angular contain exits with status 1. There is no error message to help me figure out what the error is.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add less bash jq curl wget zip git openssh
WORKDIR /app
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./src/admin/build:/var/www
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  admin:
    image: angular # Custom image
    build: .
    working_dir: /app
    command: sh -c "yarn && yarn run watch" # "watch" = "ng build --watch"
    volumes:
      - ./src/admin:/app
```

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose stop
$ docker inspect admin_1 | jq '.[0].State'
{
  "Status": "exited",
  "Running": false,
  "Paused": false,
  "Restarting": false,
  "OOMKilled": false,
  "Dead": false,
  "Pid": 0,
  "ExitCode": 1,
  "Error": "",
  "StartedAt": "2020-09-30T01:10:29.063483594Z",
  "FinishedAt": "2020-09-30T01:10:49.396912972Z"
}
```

The docker logs show nothing unexpected, other than:

```
nginx_1 exited with code 0
admin_1 exited with code 1
```

Why isn't the angular container exiting cleanly with exit code 0?

Comment: did you try to check with `docker logs admin_1`?

Comment: Yes, logs show the normal setup, angular build process, and then the exit code of 1. No other messages, errors or any useful information :(